# Spring Oauth2 without spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-restcontroller

i configured my spring rest application with java configuration for spring Oauth2 but getting 404 file not found while accessing the path /oauth/token.

Can anyone provide any suggestions  for any missed configuration. The below codes are my configurations.

```
@Configuration 
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authManager);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory().withClient("cl").secret("12").authorizedGrantTypes("password").scopes("read,write");
    }

}
```

for security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("test").password("123").authorities("USER");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

and this the web.xml java configuration

```
public class WebConf implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ap = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ap.register(AppConf.class);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic serv = ctx.addServlet("dispatcherrservlet", new DispatcherServlet(ap));
        serv.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        serv.addMapping("/");

    }

}
```

Comment: You'd need to share your code and let us know what you've already tried.

Comment: i have edited my question and added the java code which was used for configuration

Comment: I would suggest you reword your question. Currently you asking for a a link to GitHub rather than a solution. Asking for an off-site resource is off-topic (see #4: [help/on-topic]). If you reword this question such that it is asking for how to solve this, rather than a pointer to something showing how to solve this, it would not be off-topic for that reason.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: can anyone have suggestions regarding this